# View History of payment and update it in database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a problem with creating a website using ASP.NET.

I am doing a View History feature in which a user, after making a payment and attending the event, can write feedback in a Review page that contains the seminar details and payment details.

When I am retrieving from the database and have some Review History from a past event, it works. This is done by manual adding a review and a rating for an id through a Review table.

However, when I want to retrieve a seminar that the user has attended, BUT NOT reviewed the seminar, the error message occurs:

```
system.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range.
```

The line producing the error is the following:

```
Review c = reviews[gvSeminar.SelectedIndex];
```

Upon debugging, I realized that the value: reviews has a value of Count: 1. The funny thing is that when I clicked on an id THAT HAS a review and a rating, the value: reviews also has a value of Count: 1. Therefore, for the id that DID NOT have a review, the program showed an Out Of Range message since there is no review or ratings under this portion.

```
 Review c = reviews[gvSeminar.SelectedIndex];
 tbxRating.Text = c.Rating.ToString();
 tbxRemarks.Text = c.Remarks;
```

I want to make it work if the data is `null`, since there are no reviews or ratings by default, so the user can write some feedback into the View History.

View History (when selecting the past event or new event in the gridview of `ViewHistory.aspx`):

```
...
{
    Panel1.Visible = true;
    Member m = (Member)Session["user"];
    List<ShoppingCart> shoppingcarts = ShoppingCartDBMgr.getAllShoppingCart(m.Email);
    gvSeminar.DataSource = shoppingcarts;
    gvSeminar.DataBind();
    List<Seminar> seminars = SeminarMgr.getAllSeminar();
    List<Schedule> schedules = ScheduleMgr.getAllSchedule();
    List<Review> reviews = ReviewDBMgr.getAllReviewById(m.Email);
    Seminar a = seminars[gvSeminar.PageSize * gvSeminar.PageIndex + gvSeminar.SelectedIndex];
    Schedule b = schedules[gvSeminar.SelectedIndex];
    if (reviews != null)
    {
        Review c = reviews[gvSeminar.SelectedIndex];
        tbxRating.Text = c.Rating.ToString();
        tbxRemarks.Text = c.Remarks;
    }
    else
    {
        Review r = new Review()
        {
            Rating = Convert.ToInt32(tbxRating.Text),
            Remarks = tbxRemarks.Text
        };
        int id = ReviewDBMgr.insertReview(r);
        lblOutput.Text = id + "Added!";
    }

    tbxId.Text = a.Id;
    tbxName.Text = a.Name;
    tbxPrice.Text = a.Price.ToString();
    tbxDate.Text = b.Date.ToShortDateString();
}
```

Update button to add the review:

```
...
{
    Member m = (Member)Session["user"];
    List<ShoppingCart> shoppingcarts = ShoppingCartDBMgr.getAllShoppingCart(m.Email);
    gvSeminar.DataSource = shoppingcarts;
    gvSeminar.DataBind();
    List<Review> reviews = ReviewDBMgr.getAllReviewById(m.Email);

    if (reviews == null)
    {
        Review c = reviews[gvSeminar.SelectedIndex];
        tbxRating.Text = c.Rating.ToString();
        tbxRemarks.Text = c.Remarks;
        Review r = new Review()
        {
            Rating = Convert.ToInt32(tbxRating.Text),
            Remarks = tbxRemarks.Text
        };
        int id = ReviewDBMgr.insertReview(r);
        lblOutput.Text = id + "Added!";
    }
}
```

Database Manager:

```
public static int insertReview(Review r)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
    try
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = con;
        command.CommandText = "insert into Review (rev_rating, rev_remarks, sem_id, participant_email) values (@rev_rating, @rev_remarks, @sem_id, @participant_email)";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rev_rating", r.Rating);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rev_remarks", r.Remarks);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sem_id", r.Seminar.Id);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@participant_email", r.Member.Email);
        con.Open();
        return command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: have you check your inserted value in database Review table ?

Comment: when i select the data is null, i got an error message and also cannot insert the statement into database

Comment: Please tell us exactly what line causes the error and the entire exception details as an edit to your question, not here in the comments.

Comment: you are passing m.Email in ReviewDBMgr.getAllReviewById(m.Email) is it right ?

Comment: ya, i am passing an email to check whether this person or not into the payment list

Answer (score 0):

This your insert command

```
command.CommandText = "insert into Review (rev_rating, rev_remarks, sem_id, participant_email) values (@rev_rating, @rev_remarks, @sem_id, @participant_email)";
```

To **Udpate** value in table you have change it to

```
command.CommandText = "UPDATE Review SET rev_rating = @rev_rating, rev_remarks = @rev_remarks Where sem_id = @sem_id";
```

Comment: So, i changed it from insert statement to become update ? is it sounds better ? because i am getting null value from the data, if the data is null.

Comment: please check above comment for null value : )